# How to combine winter months of two consecutive years

Tags: r, time-series

I have a count data of several species spanning over several years. I want to look at the abundance dynamics for each species over winter season only for each year. The problem is winter season span over two years, November, December and January of next year. Now, I want to combine the abundance of each species of winter months spanning over two consecutive years and do some analysis. For example, I want to subset Nov-Dec of 2005 and Jan of 2006 in first round and do some analysis with this then in second round want to subset Nov-Dec of 2006 and Jan of 2007 and then repeat the same analysis and so on....  How can I do it in R?

Here is an example of the data

```
date    species year    month   day abundance   temp
9/3/2005    A   2005    9   3   3   19
9/15/2005   B   2005    9   15  30  16
10/4/2005   A   2005    10  4   24  12
11/6/2005   A   2005    11  6   32  14
12/8/2005   A   2005    12  8   15  13
1/3/2005    A   2006    1   3   64  19
1/4/2006    B   2006    1   4   2   13
2/10/2006   A   2006    2   10  56  12
2/8/2006    A   2006    1   3   34  19
3/9/2006    A   2006    1   3   64  19
```

Comment: easy way to deal with this would be to add a column for Month and subset the data based on the month of the year. which are winter months, if you can provide us reproducible example using dput. I can help you more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I convert your date column to a date class (possibly with `lubridate`) and remove the year month day columns as they are redundant.

Then make a new column with the seasonal year (defined as the year, unless the month is Jan, then it is the previous year). A further column is made with `case_when` that defines the row's season.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# converts to date format
df$date <- mdy(df$date)

# add in columns
df <- mutate(df,
       season_year = ifelse(month(date) == 1, year(date) - 1, year(date)),
       season = case_when(
        month(date) %in% c(2, 3, 4) ~ "Spring",
        month(date) %in% c(5, 6, 7) ~ "Summer",
        month(date) %in% c(8, 9, 10) ~ "Autumn",
        month(date) %in% c(11, 12, 1) ~ "Winter",
        T ~ NA_character_
       ))

#          date species abundance temp season_year season
# 1  2005-09-03       A         3   19        2005 Autumn
# 2  2005-09-15       B        30   16        2005 Autumn
# 3  2005-10-04       A        24   12        2005 Autumn
# 4  2005-11-06       A        32   14        2005 Winter
# 5  2005-12-08       A        15   13        2005 Winter
# 6  2005-01-03       A        64   19        2004 Winter
# 7  2006-01-04       B         2   13        2005 Winter
# 8  2006-02-10       A        56   12        2006 Spring
# 9  2006-02-08       A        34   19        2006 Spring
# 10 2006-03-09       A        64   19        2006 Spring
```

Then you can `group_by()` and/or `filter()` your data for further analysis:

```
df %>%
  group_by(season_year) %>%
  filter(season == "Winter") %>%
  summarise(count = sum(abundance))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   season_year count
#         <dbl> <int>
# 1        2004    64
# 2        2005    49
```

Answer (score 2):

data.table solution:

first create a lookup-table with from-to dates and the season-year, then perform an overlap-join using `foverlaps`

```
library( data.table )
```

**sample data**

```
dt <- fread("date    species year    month   day abundance   temp
9/3/2005    A   2005    9   3   3   19
9/15/2005   B   2005    9   15  30  16
10/4/2005   A   2005    10  4   24  12
11/6/2005   A   2005    11  6   32  14
12/8/2005   A   2005    12  8   15  13
1/3/2005    A   2006    1   3   64  19
1/4/2006    B   2006    1   4   2   13
2/10/2006   A   2006    2   10  56  12
2/8/2006    A   2006    1   3   34  19
3/9/2006    A   2006    1   3   64  19", header = TRUE)
```

**create a lookup-table**

In here, you define the names, start and end of the seasons. Adjust to your own needs. Since you want to analyse the seasons individually, I advise to keep unique season-names (here: based on start-year of the season).

```
dt.season <- data.table( from = seq( as.Date("1999-02-01"), length.out = 100, by = "3 month"),
                         to = seq( as.Date("1999-05-01"), length.out = 100, by = "3 month") - 1 )
dt.season[, season := paste0( c( "spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter" ), "-", year( from ) )]
setkey( dt.season, from, to )

head(dt.season,6)

#          from         to      season
# 1: 1999-02-01 1999-04-30 spring-1999
# 2: 1999-05-01 1999-07-31 summer-1999
# 3: 1999-08-01 1999-10-31 autumn-1999
# 4: 1999-11-01 2000-01-31 winter-1999
# 5: 2000-02-01 2000-04-30 spring-2000
# 6: 2000-05-01 2000-07-31 summer-2000
```

**and perform join**

```
#set dt$date as dates
dt[, date := as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")]

#create dummy variables to join on
dt[, `:=`( from = date, to = date)]

#create an overlap join, and clean the dummies used for the join
foverlaps( dt, dt.season)[, `:=`(from = NULL, to = NULL, i.from = NULL, i.to = NULL)][]

#         season       date species year month day abundance temp
#  1: autumn-2005 2005-09-03       A 2005     9   3         3   19
#  2: autumn-2005 2005-09-15       B 2005     9  15        30   16
#  3: autumn-2005 2005-10-04       A 2005    10   4        24   12
#  4: winter-2005 2005-11-06       A 2005    11   6        32   14
#  5: winter-2005 2005-12-08       A 2005    12   8        15   13
#  6: winter-2004 2005-01-03       A 2006     1   3        64   19
#  7: winter-2005 2006-01-04       B 2006     1   4         2   13
#  8: spring-2006 2006-02-10       A 2006     2  10        56   12
#  9: spring-2006 2006-02-08       A 2006     1   3        34   19
# 10: spring-2006 2006-03-09       A 2006     1   3        64   19
```

You can now easily group/sum/analyse by `season`

Answer (score 1):

I'd think the easiest way would be to consider that 2006 winter consists of Nov, Dec 2006 and Jan 2007, you could add a column `winterid <- ifelse(data$month %in% c(11,12), data$year, ifelse(data$month == 1, data$year-1, "notwinter"))`.
You are now able to subset on the successive winter seasons. Adapt according to your notation.